# iOS: Best Way to do This w/o Calling Method 32 Times?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, iteration, nsdictionary, game-center

I'm currently retrieving the Top 100 Scores for one of my leaderboards the following way:

```
- (void) retrieveTop100Scores {

__block int totalScore = 0;

GKLeaderboard *myLB = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
myLB.identifier = [Team currentTeam];
myLB.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
myLB.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
myLB.range = NSMakeRange(1, 100);

[myLB loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    if (scores != nil) {

        for (GKScore *score in scores) {

            NSLog(@"%lld", score.value);

            totalScore += score.value;

        }

        NSLog(@"Total Score: %d", totalScore);
        [self loadingDidEnd];
    }
}];
```

}

The problem is I want to do this for 32 leaderboards. I have an array with all 32 leaderboard identifiers:

```
NSArray *leaderboardIDs;
```

**So my question is, how can I combine those 2 segments of code to pull in the 100 values for each leaderboard, resulting in a dictionary with all of the leaderboard names as keys, and the Total (of each 100 scores) of the leaderboards for values.**

## UPDATED:

So I have updated my answer using CrimsonChris' help. The only question I have is, how can I know when it is done totaling the score for all 32 teams? The reason I ask, is because I would then like to organize them from highest to lowest, and display them in that order in a tableView.

This is what I've updated my answer to:

In my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)loadLeaderboardData {

// Array of leaderboard ID's to get high scores for
NSArray *leaderboardIDs = @[@"algeria", @"argentina", @"australia", @"belgium", @"bosniaandherzegovina", @"brazil", @"cameroon", @"chile", @"colombia", @"costarica", @"croatia", @"ecuador", @"england", @"france", @"germany", @"ghana", @"greece", @"honduras", @"iran", @"italy", @"ivorycoast", @"japan", @"mexico", @"netherlands", @"nigeria", @"portugal", @"russia", @"southkorea", @"spain", @"switzerland", @"unitedstates", @"uruguay"];

    scoresByLeaderboardID = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    __block int requestCount = (int)leaderboardIDs.count;
    for (NSString *leaderboardID in leaderboardIDs) {
        [self loadScoresForLeaderboardID:leaderboardID range:NSMakeRange(1, 100) callback:^(NSArray *scores) {
            scoresByLeaderboardID[leaderboardID] = scores;
            if (--requestCount <= 0) { 
                if (callback)callback(scoresByLeaderboardID);
            }
        }];
    }
}



- (void)loadScoresForLeaderboardID:(NSString*)leaderboardID range:(NSRange)range callback:(CallbackBlock)callback {

__block int totalScore = 0;

GKLeaderboard *myLB = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
myLB.identifier = leaderboardID;
myLB.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
myLB.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
myLB.range = range;

[myLB loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        //NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    if (scores != nil) {
        for (GKScore *score in scores) {
            //NSLog(@"Individual Scores: %lld (For %@)", score.value, leaderboardID);
        }

    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Hint: `__block int totalScore = 0;` You already know how to modify ints in blocks, and all you really want to do is count to 32.

Comment: Thanks James. That definitely led me in the right direction!

Comment: I notice that you're not using the callback block. That's a problem. Instead of calling `[self loadingDidEnd]` call `if (callback) callback(scores)`.

Comment: You are getting that callback not recognized error because your method `-(void)loadLeaderboardData` does not declare a callback! Change it to match match my method signature.

Comment: Also, view controllers are a terrible place for loading code. I would recommend moving it into a class who's only job is to load leaderboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method can be cleaned up by using callback blocks.

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object);

//callback accepts an NSArray* of GKScore*
- (void)loadScoresForLeaderboardID:(NSString *)leaderboardID range:(NSRange)range callback:(CallbackBlock)callback {
    GKLeaderboard *myLB = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    myLB.identifier = leaderboardID;
    myLB.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    myLB.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
    myLB.range = range;

    [myLB loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        if (callback) callback(scores);
    }];
}
```

You can then loop over your leaderboards.

```
//callback accepts an NSDictionary* of NSArray*(of GKScore*) by NSNumber*
- (void)loadScoresForLeaderboardIDs:(NSArray *)leaderboardIDs withCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback { 
    NSMutableDictionary *scoresByLeaderboardID = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    __block int requestCount = leaderboardIDs.count;
    for (NSString *leaderboardID in leaderboardIDs) {
        [LeaderboardLoader loadScoresForLeaderboardID:leaderboardID range:NSMakeRange(1, 100) callback:^(NSArray *scores) {
            scoresByLeaderboardID[leaderboardID] = scores;
            if (--requestCount <= 0) { //not thread safe
                if (callback) callback(scoresByLeaderboardID);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Once this method fires its callback you should have all your scores.

```
[LeaderboardLoader loadScoresForLeaderboardIDs:@[@"FirstID", @"SecondID", @"ThirdID"] withCallback:^(NSDictionary *scoresByLeaderboardID) {
    NSLog(@"%@", scoresByLeaderboardID);
    //do whatever you need to with all your scores here.
}];
```

Comment: Thank you @CrimsonChris! I have updated my answer with the suggestions you provided, now I just have a couple of questions. How can I find out when it is done totaling the score for all 32 leaderboards, and is this the most efficient way? Thanks so much!

Comment: You keep a count of your responses and then fire off a completion block when they all finish.

Comment: Thanks CrimsonChris. That explains why at the end, my scoresByLeaderboardID was empty. Only problem is that the line if (callback) callback(scoresByLeaderboardID); returns "implicit declaration of callback is invalid in c99"

Comment: Are you using the same method signature that I posted? It has a callback declared.

Comment: I added typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object); to the top of my .m file, and this is the method: - (void)loadScoresForLeaderboardID:(NSString*)leaderboardID range:(NSRange)range callback:(CallbackBlock)callback

Comment: That typedef needs to be visible wherever it is being used. Is your error in a different file like the .h?

Comment: It's right under my imports, but above my@interface & implementation. I did change the method you suggested from an NSNUmber to an NSString

Comment: Which method has the error in it? You seem confused, I've updated my answer to closer match the code you've posted.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clearer what I'm doing, I'll look over your answer real quick. By the way thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I did what you mentioned about splitting it into a seperate class, and it works perfectly. Appreciate the help! I'll be reading a lot more about callback blocks they're awesome!

Comment: You should also look into how to make that one method thread safe. It has the potential to fail if the the last callbacks run at exactly the same time. It won't happen all the time but of it fails you won't get your callback. It's such a common scenario in business applications that I've written an AyncBlockRunner class to handle the thread safety.