# iOS- Saving data inside a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I've been struggling on this for several days so any would be appreciated. I'm trying to save the players array below and display it in a UITableView. I'd like to save it so I can display the local player's friends. I've tried several different things but something that looks it's working for others is this.

```
__block NSArray *friends;

- (void) loadPlayerData: (NSArray *) identifiers {
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        if (players != nil) {
            friends = players;
            NSLog(@"Inside: %@", friends); //Properly shows the array
        }
     }];
    NSLog(@"Outside: %@", friends): //Doesn't work, shows nil
}
```

But friends is still nil/null afterwards. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to save players and use it in a UITableView? Thanks.

*****EDIT*****

So here's the solution I put together.

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object);

+ (void) retrieveFriends: (CallbackBlock)callback {
    GKLocalPlayer *lp = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    if (lp.authenticated) {
        [lp loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *friends, NSError *error) {
    if (friends != nil) {
        [self loadPlayerDataWithIdentifiers:friends callback:^(NSArray *playersInfo) {
        if (callback) callback(playersInfo);
        }]; 
      }
    }];

  }
}

+ (void) loadPlayerDataWithIdentifiers: (NSArray *) identifiers callback:(CallbackBlock)callback {


  [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
  if (error != nil) {
     // Handle the error.
  }
  if (players != nil) {
     if (callback) callback(players);
  }
  }];
}
```

The only thing is, my UITableView is in another class so I tried doing this and making the two methods above public. `info` isn't printing out anything. Any ideas?

```
[GameCenterHelper retrieveFriends:^(NSArray *info) {
    NSLog(@"Friends Info: %@", info);
}];
```

Comment: Asynchronous code does **NOT** run sequentially (top to bottom). You are hitting your log before friends is ever set. Here's an example of how you should be doing this using callback blocks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154141/ios-best-way-to-do-this-w-o-calling-method-32-times/24154482#24154482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use callback blocks.

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id object);

- (void)loadPlayerDataWithIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers callback:(CallbackBlock)callback {
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        if (callback) callback(players);
    }];
}
```

You imply in your question that this is for a table view. If so, you need to reload your table after the data has been loaded.

```
[self loadPlayerDataWithIdentifiers:identifiers callback:^(NSArray *players) {
    self.players = players;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one quick question, I'm calling loadPlayerDataWithIdentifiers from another block called `loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *friends, NSError *error`. Originally I was just passing in `friends` for the identifiers parameter. What is supposed to be passed in for callback?

Answer (score 0):

Crimson Chris is correct. 
The other option is use GCD to wait for the response to comeback.
Or change this to synchronous call as you want to get the results immediately.